# How to automate moving Excel content and graphs into Powerpoint when links aren't an option?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDuaK.png)Feel free to point me to the answer to this if I missed it in my searching and THANK YOU IN ADVANCE for any help!

I Follow a process that creates new Excel worksheets and Powerpoint slides for each project (so I can't just set up files with static links to existing slides and worksheets).  I am curious if (and if so, how) a macro could be used to automate the following:

Look at an Excel workbook and populate the same Powerpoint Slide with three pieces of information for each graph found in the Powerpoint:

1. A title (this will be perhaps five words in the same cell in each worksheet)
2. A text box (this will be a sentence in another cell in each worksheet)
3. A graph (there is a placeholder "click to add text" box in the Powerpoint cell formatted for the size and location I want the graph to populate).

The macro should then repeat this for every graph it finds in the Excel file using the title and text box information in the worksheet where the graph is located.

Key details:

1. The workbook will contain numerous worksheets with identical format.  Each worksheet will contain one Title (#1 above...in cell A1) and one Text Box (#2 above...in cell B1), but several dozen different graphs.
2. While all the worksheets are identical in format, the graphs change based on what data is contained in each respective worksheet.
3. A typical project might have 50 worksheets, each containing 15 graphs.
4. Every graph will populate a copy of the same Powerpoint slide template so that slide gets duplicated 500+ times as the deck is created.
5. So, for example, 15 slides might have the same title and Text Box content, but each will have different graphs...then the next 15 have a different title and Text Box and 15 unique graphs...and the next 15 will be yet another title and Text Box and 15 unique graphs.
6. I am using Microsoft Office for Mac 2016.

I have attached an image to the Powerpoint slide with the three locations to insert info from Excel and part of one Excel worksheet (the graphs continue to the right).

Any thoughts or directions are greatly appreciated.  Needless to say, this is not a fun task to repeat 500 times.

[image]

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Comment: Thanks Booster_d16!  It looks like pptxbuilder.com could be the solution I'm looking for.